# Python How to count how many times each of the vocabulary words shows in the sentence?

Tags: python, string, word-count

hey guys Im confused and very unsure why my code is not working. what I am doing in this code is trying to find certain words from a list in a sentence I have and output the number of times it is repeated within the sentence.

```
vocabulary =["in","on","to","www"]
numwords = [0,0,0,0]
mysentence = (" ʺAlso the sea tosses itself and breaks itself, and should any  sleeper fancying that he might find on the beach an answer to his doubts, a  sharer of his solitude, throw off his bedclothes and go down by himself to  walk on the sand, no image with semblance of serving and divine  promptitude comes readily to hand bringing the night to order and making  the world reflect the compass of the soul.ʺ)
for word in mysentence.split():
              if (word == vocabulary):
                  else:
                  numwords[0] += 1
              if(word == vocabulary):
                  else:
                  numwords[1] +=1
              if (word == vocabulary):
                  else:
                  numwords [2] += 1
              if (word == vocabulary):
                  else :
                  numwords [3] += 1
              if (word == vocabulary):
                  else:
                  numwords [4] += 1


print "total number of words : " + str(len(mysentence))
```

Comment: Please update the code int the question.

Comment: What is the expected output for the code example you gave?

Comment: Is the code displaying here the same way it is on your machine?

Comment: Have a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). The examples there will help with the usage.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried. Read more on how to ask questions, if you want points and such.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `collections.Counter` to count all the words in the sentence, and then look up the ones you're interested in.

```
from collections import Counter
vocabulary =["in","on","to","www"]
mysentence = "Also the sea tosses itself and breaks itself, and should any  sleeper fancying that he might find on the beach an answer to his doubts, a  sharer of his solitude, throw off his bedclothes and go down by himself to  walk on the sand, no image with semblance of serving and divine  promptitude comes readily to hand bringing the night to order and making  the world reflect the compass of the soul."
mysentence = mysentence.split()
c = Counter(mysentence)
numwords = [c[i] for i in vocabulary]
print(numwords)
```

Comment: This is the Pythonic way to do it. A bit advanced for a beginner maybe, but generalizes well. The list comprehension is elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you could iterate through the list with a for loop checking if it's in the list and then incrementing the counter - an example implementation might look like

```
def find_word(word,string):
    word_count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if list[i] == word:
            word_count +=1
```

This might be a little inefficient, but I'm sure it might be easier to understand for you than collections.Counter :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this honestly to check:

```
for word in mysentence.split():
    if word in vocabulary:
        numwords[vocabulary.index(word)] += 1
```

Therefore your entire code would look like this:

```
vocabulary = ["in", "on", "to", "www"]
numwords = [0, 0, 0, 0]
mysentence = (" ʺAlso the sea tosses itself and breaks itself, and should any  sleeper fancying that he might find on the beach an answer to his doubts, a  sharer of his solitude, throw off his bedclothes and go down by himself to  walk on the sand, no image with semblance of serving and divine  promptitude comes readily to hand bringing the night to order and making  the world reflect the compass of the soul.ʺ")
for word in mysentence.replace('.', '').replace(',', '').split():
    if word in vocabulary:
        numwords[vocabulary.index(word)] += 1

print("total number of words : " + str(len(mysentence)))
```

As @Jacob suggested, replacing the '.' and ',' characters can also be applied before the split, to avoid any possible conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the issue that characters like “ and ” may not parse well unless an appropriate encoding scheme has been specified.

```
this_is_how_you_define_a_string = "The string goes here"

# and thus:

mysentence = "Also the sea tosses itself and breaks itself, and should any  sleeper fancying that he might find on the beach an answer to his doubts, a  sharer of his solitude, throw off his bedclothes and go down by himself to  walk on the sand, no image with semblance of serving and divine  promptitude comes readily to hand bringing the night to order and making  the world reflect the compass of the soul."

for v in vocabulary:
    v in mysentence # Notice the indentation of 4 spaces
```

This solution will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if v i sin mysentence. I think I will leave as an exercise how to accumulate the values. Hint: TRUE == 1 and FALSE = 0. You need the sum of the true values for each word `v`.

Comment: Should this be a generator of some kind?  You're missing `yield` and some kind of `def` statement